# Is there a way to have Rails automatically bust an HTML cache when a linked asset changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, webpacker

Say I've got a Rails controller that uses `fresh_when` to enable [conditional GET](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#conditional-get-support) support:

```rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { fresh_when @accounts }
    end
  end
end
```

This ensures that if no `Account` records are added or updated, the app will *not render the response HTML*, and will instead respond with a 304 status. The browser will then display its own cached HTML page.

This is all fine, **except when a linked JavaScript asset has changed**.

The layout file for this app likely has one or both of the following lines:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag :application %>
```

If the browser uses it's cached HTML content, that content might be linking to a stale JS asset. That JS request would then either encounter a 404 (because the asset is no longer available) or it would receive the old JS file, potentially causing unexpected JS bugs.

I'd assumed that Webpacker and/or Sprockets (depending on how the JS file is included) would handle this scenario for me, but I no longer think that's the case. In my app, I've had to add the following link to `ApplicationController`:

```rb
etag { Webpacker.manifest.lookup! 'application.js' }
```

This includes the JavaScript fingerprint into the Etag generated by `fresh_when`, so any changes to 'application.js' will bust the HTML cache.

How are other people handling this scenario? Am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: It will be nice to know. I never read it before.

Comment: My brain is hurting trying to figure out why I’ve never faced this problem before. Maybe the overall freshness system takes the template into account as well? Anyway, one possible solution is include the file’s hash in the cache key. I think there’s an api for that. So `fresh_when [@accounts, asset_sig(‘foo.js’)]`

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what the `etag` method does.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet/ClassMethods.html#method-i-etag